# INotifyPropertyChanged PropertyChanged event remains null

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have searched on the forum and some other sources regarding PropertyChanged event remains null but didn't find any solution. I had created a sample WPF app with AModel ,AViewModel and MainWindow. Model and ViewModel has implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface but when checked at runtime both PropertyChanged events remains null. Application Code is as below:

```
public class AModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AModel()
    {

    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyname = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
    private string _A;
    public string A
    {
        get
        {
            return _A;
        }
        set
        {
            _A = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("A");
        }
    }
}

public class AViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyname = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
    public AViewModel()
    {
        MyList = new List<AModel>();

    }

    private List<AModel> _MyList;
    public List<AModel> MyList
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyList;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyList = value;
        }
    }


}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private AViewModel _objViewModel=new AViewModel();
    public AViewModel ObjViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _objViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            _objViewModel = value;
        }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ObjViewModel = new AViewModel();
        DataContext = ObjViewModel;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObjViewModel.MyList.Add(new AModel() { A = "Sample Text" });
    }
}
```

Now when i add breakpoint to my model class PropertyChanged event it is always null. I had created object of view model and assigned that to the DataContext of MainWindow but still its null. I am not able to understand where I am going wrong in this simple application. I had checked binding which is working properly.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you doing with `MyList`  in the view? As long as the view doesn't bind to a property of an AModel element of that collection, its PropertyChanged event will of course be null. In order to make `ObjViewModel.MyList.Add` update the view, use an ObservableCollection, i.e. `public ObservableCollection<AModel> MyList`.

Comment: @Clemens MyList is used to bind with a DataGrid in MainWindow and AModel Property A is binded with that datagrid column. I know about observable collection but I want to find the issue why property change event remains null that if DataContext is assigned to MainWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PropertyChanged event is null here because the property is not actually getting changed. You are creating a collection and then binding it to an UI control. If you want to see a property changed getting triggered, then you can try this :-

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Margin="20" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding A,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button  Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20" Content="Click Me" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
```

So, when you will try to update the item in the textbox :-

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding A,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

then you will notice that the property changed is being triggered as soon as you type in the TextBox:-

```
{Method = {Void OnPropertyChanged(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)}}
```

Please comment if you need more clarification.

Comment: The explanation is totally wrong. The PropertyChanged event is *not* null just because the property is not changed in the UI. It is most certainly null because there is no Binding. I'm saying *most certainly* because we did not see the XAML and can't know for sure. Anyway, be aware that `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` has *nothing* to do with the `PropertyChanged` event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. It's two different things which accidentially have the same name.

Comment: Yes. UpdateSourceTrigger has nothing to do with property changed. Here in this case, on calling 

ObjViewModel.MyList.Add(new AModel() { A = "Sample Text" });

PropertyChanged is null, because the Binding is still not existing. It is just a plain POCO being created so the PropertyChanged is null. But when the binding is already there, then a PropertyChanged gets attached which is why it will work. The example I provided shows this. Its is bad that @Clemens only noticed the PropertyChanged and not the solution.

Comment: So, Pankaj, the property changed will not get triggered when you don't have the binding available. In your case, you mentioned that you are binding it to a DataGrid and it is displaying fine, but, it is after the item has been added to the list. The PropertyChanged event gets attached after it has been displayed in the UI. 

In the example I gave, I am updating it in a template after the UI has been rendered, so the PropertyChanged is not null. The update source trigger just mentions when to update the property, immediately or on losing focus or explicit, with each control has default way.

Comment: @Clemens, about your comment "The PropertyChanged event is not null just because the property is not changed in the UI. It is most certainly null because there is no Binding."
Even if there is a binding, the property changed can be null initially. The event PropertyChanged gets attached when the control is rendered. Once the control is rendered, then any change in property will have a PropertyChanged event not null.